# How to end the input stream in java

Tags: java

I am trying to close inputstream using input.close(), but I am unable to do so.

```
              try {

        String line;
        Set<String> folderList = new HashSet<>();

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec(new String[] { "cmd", "/K", "dir \"c:\\Program Files\\apache-tomcat-*\" /s" });

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine().trim()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("<DIR>")) {

                String folder = line.substring(line.indexOf("<DIR>") + "<DIR>".length()).trim();
                // System.out.println("c:\\Program Files" + "\\" + folder + "\\lib\\");
                String path = "c:\\Program Files" + "\\" + folder + "\\lib\\";
                folderList.add(folder);
                System.out.println(path);

            }

        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println("****");  // unreachable code error is I am not able to go out of the while loop.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm not able to reproduce this, can you update complete code

Comment: Why are you calling `dir` as an external process and parsing its output instead of just using Java’s builtin API to get the contents of directories?

Answer (score 0):

you can put your bufferedreader in a try clause and it gets automatically closed.

```
String line;
Set<String> folderList = new HashSet<>();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
            .exec(new String[] { "cmd", "/K", "dir \"c:\\Program Files\\apache-tomcat-*\" /s" });


try(BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
    while ((line = input.readLine().trim()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("<DIR>")) {

            String folder = line.substring(line.indexOf("<DIR>") + "<DIR>".length()).trim();
            // System.out.println("c:\\Program Files" + "\\" + folder + "\\lib\\");
            String path = "c:\\Program Files" + "\\" + folder + "\\lib\\";
            folderList.add(folder);
            System.out.println(path);

        }
    }
    System.out.println("****"); 
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also, `(line = input.readLine().trim()) != null` has the potential to throw an NullPointerException when `input.readLine()` returns null.

Comment: That will indeed close the `BufferedReader`, even when the `NullPointerException` caused by calling `trim()` on the result of `readLine()` before checking it for `null` happens.

Answer (score 0):

`input.readLine()` will return null to indicate end-of-stream.

Calling `trim()` will throw `NullPointerException` if `readLine()` returned null, so value assigned to `line` is *guaranteed* to not be null.

That means `while (line != null)` is **always true**, and hence the loop will never end.

The compiler is correct, the code after the loop is unreachable.

You need to call `trim` *after* checking for null value:

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.trim();
    if (line.contains("<DIR>")) {
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the above but still I am facing same issue.

Comment: Please help me with this issue. I am unable to resolve.

Comment: You are correct in that calling `trim()` on the result of `readLine()` will lead to a `NullPointerException`, but the standard Java compiler is not smart enough to deduce that `trim()` will never return `null`, to consider the loop as infinite. This should not produce an error regarding unreachable code. The problem seems to be connected with what the OP did not post yet.